# Adding a file from file system to a specific folder inside a jar

Tags: java, command-line, jar

Quick question (sorry struggling with time)

How can I add any file from my file system under `WEB-INF/classes` folder in a jar file? I am trying this with jar command but it copies a file in a jar with its absolute path meaning if I create a file at `E:\folder1\WEB-INF\classes` folder and try to add it to a jar it creates `folder1/WEB-INF/classes` folder inside the jar and places the file into it.

I used jar command as below

`jar -uvf E:\folder1\sample.jar E:\folder1\WEB-INF\classes\pkfe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specifiy the `-C`-switch and alter the file-argument like so:

```
jar -uvf E:\folder1\sample.jar -C E:\folder1 WEB-INF\classes\pkfe
```

This makes the command run within `E:\folder1` and include the files relative from that location

You can also add entire folders this way:

```
jar -uvf -uvf E:\folder1\sample.jar -C E:\folder1 .
```

The `.` tells the command to add everything at the location of the working directory (`E:\folder1`). You need to move your sample.jar to somewhere else, otherwise you would softlock the command, as it would be adding itsself to itsself into eternity...

Several specific files within a folder would work like this

```
jar -uvf E:\folder1\sample.jar -C E:\folder1 WEB-INF\classes\pkfe -C E:\folder1 WEB-INF\classes\secondFile.dat -C E:\folder1 org\blupp\blah\thirdFile.class
```

Source: `jar -?`

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked like a charm. Also, how can I pass multiple files in ```WEB-INF\classes``` with names as it only worked for me on passing the -C switch pattern again for a second file I was trying to include?

Comment: Thanks for the update!!! I was creating 3 files post build which I wanted to add in the jar. For this I had to specify them with their ```-C``` switches separately (as you also mentioned) and it worked.